# On Synology DS218play, WordPress cannot connect to the user database, but phpmyadmin can

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mariadb, synology

I am facing some issues while setting up my Synology *DS218play*. I hope you will be able to help me. Here is my current configuration :

I have a virtual host set with the `Web Station` app

- Domain : blog.domain.com
- Directory : web/blog.domain.com/wordpress/
- HTTP Server : Nginx
- PHP version : 7.0
- HSTS and HTTP/2 checked

I have installed the *MariaDB 10* and *phpmyadmin* packages from Synology Community repository.
I can log into phpmyadmin with root user, hence I created a `blog` user and a 'blog' database. `blog` user is granted with all privileges for `blog` database. I set `localhost` to hostname for `blog` user. I guess SQL Server is listening through 3306 port by default, I don't see where I can check or edit this.

I can log into phpmyadmin with my `blog` user, and I see only the `blog` database (and information_schema, I assume it is normal).

Here comes the problem : When I try to go to https://blog.domain.com, it redirects me to https://blog.domain.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php, I press 'Let's go!' and enter my credentials :

- user : blog
- password :
- hostname : localhost
- database name : blog
- table prefix : wp_ (default value)

And when I validate, I go to an error page : error establishing a database connection. I triple checked user/password, it works into phpmyadmin and not with WordPress. So I assume the error comes from hostname, or phpmyadmin configuration to allow the connection from outside the phpmyadmin's interface. I would like to test directly on my NAS with mysql command line, but I have not found any solution to do that.

NB: I don't know if it is useful, but I set up my router to redirect the port 3306 to my NAS. It did not change anything.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are phpmyadmin and WordPress on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, all is on the same machine : the Synology DS218play host the HTTP server with phpmyadmin and the WordPress, the SQL Server (Maria DB 10).

Comment: "SQL Server" is a totally different product than "MariaDB".

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache instead of Nginx here, but I had the exact same problem on my Synology. It was solved by changing the hostname from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1:3307`. This is the way to link to Maria DB 10. The port for Maria DB 5 would apparently be 3306 (not tested). Wordpress is now installed correctly and I can access the admin page.

But... this is not the end of the story. As soon as you will try to install a theme or a plugin, or update something, Wordpress will ask for FTP credentials to the Web Server. To make a long story short, Telnet your way as Default Admin (the SSH terminal and Admin Default User must be enabled) and type:

`sudo su`  <--- To get root access

Use the same password

`chown -R http:http /volume1/web/myfoldername`   <--- To give propre ownership

`chmod -R 775 /volume1/web/myfoldername`   <--- To give propre access privileges

Everything works well from there.